# instantiate objects and calling methods from a different class when constructing an object

Tags: django

This is my Django Reconciliation class from mytransactions app (below). Every time I do a Reconciliation, I also want to create a log object from a class called TransactionLog (see below) and call a method check_if_needs_consolidation() from a another app (mymoney) and class (Balance). How can I do it?

Reconciliation Class, mytransactions app (models.py):

```
class Reconciliation(models.Model):
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    account = models.ForeignKey('mymoney.Account',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notes
```

TransactionLog (mytransactions app, models.py)

```
class TransactionLog(models.Model):    
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('mymoney.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    beneficiary = models.ForeignKey('mybeneficiaries.Beneficiary',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_cleared = models.BooleanField("Cleared")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.beneficiary)
```

Balance class from mymoney app, and the check_if_needs_consolidation() method I want to call:

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('mymoney.account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    
    #def check_if_needs_consolidation(month):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new TransactionLog object in the save() method of the Reconciliation class. Every time a Reconciliation object is saved (i.e. newly created or updated), a TransactionLog will be made.

```
class Reconciliation(models.Model):
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    account = models.ForeignKey('mymoney.Account',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def save(self, *args, **kwarg):
        super(Reconciliation, self).save(*args, **kwarg)
        #modify the code below based on your needs
        transactionlog = TransactionLog()
        transactionlog.amount = self.amount
        transactionlog.notes = self.notes
        transactionlog.account = self.account
        #etc...
        transactionlog.save()
        #call check_if_needs_consolidation()
        self.account.balance.check_if_needs_consolidation()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notes
```

This enables you to track any changes of the Reconciliation model

Comment: I'll try that. And who is calling def save()? Don't I need an __init__? And the method check_if_needs_consolidation()? How is the correct way to call it?

Comment: The save() method is automatically called when you save an instance of a model. If you want to call the check_if_needs_consolidation() function, you could do it also in the save method of the Reconciliation model, since the model is linked to the Balance model via Foreign key. (I'll update my answer with #call check_if_needs_consolidation().